# Powershell drive configuration using loops and arrays

Tags: powershell

I created a powershell script to do some OS drive configuration but its pretty long and I'd like to shorten it, a lot. Im decent with powershell, but not looping or arrays. Im sure I could add some for loops to shorten it. Checking out examples helps me out. Sorry for the long code but its what works.

```
#PS Script to online drives, initialize, create volume, and format the volume.

# Online the 5 HDD's

set-disk -Number 1 -IsOffline $False
set-disk -Number 2 -IsOffline $False
set-disk -Number 3 -IsOffline $False
set-disk -Number 4 -IsOffline $False
set-disk -Number 5 -IsOffline $False

# Makes a read only drive writeable

set-disk -number 1 -isReadOnly $False
set-disk -number 2 -isReadOnly $False
set-disk -number 3 -isReadOnly $False
set-disk -number 4 -isReadOnly $False
set-disk -number 5 -isReadOnly $False

# Initializes the disks

Initialize-Disk -number 1 -PartitionStyle GPT
Initialize-Disk -number 2 -PartitionStyle GPT
Initialize-Disk -number 3 -PartitionStyle GPT
Initialize-Disk -number 4 -PartitionStyle GPT
Initialize-Disk -number 5 -PartitionStyle GPT

# Creates a new volume and assigns the specific drive letter

New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize
New-Partition -DiskNumber 2 -DriveLetter E -UseMaximumSize
New-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -DriveLetter F -UseMaximumSize
New-Partition -DiskNumber 4 -DriveLetter G -UseMaximumSize
New-Partition -DiskNumber 5 -DriveLetter K -UseMaximumSize

# Formats the drive with 64KB, sets it as NTFS and Labels it. 

Format-Volume -DriveLetter D -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel SQL -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
Format-Volume -DriveLetter E -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel Data -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
Format-Volume -DriveLetter F -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel Logs -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
Format-Volume -DriveLetter G -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel TembDB -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
Format-Volume -DriveLetter K -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel Backups -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I ended up writing this and it worked:

```
$drives = @()
  $drives = @("1:D:SQL","2:E:Data","3:F:Logs","4:G:TempDB","5:K:Backup")
  foreach ( $drive in $drives) {
  $volume,$letter,$label = $drive.split(':')
  set-disk -Number $volume -IsOffline $False
  set-disk -number $volume -isReadOnly $False
  Initialize-Disk -number $volume -PartitionStyle GPT
  New-Partition -DiskNumber $volume -DriveLetter $letter -UseMaximumSize
  Format-Volume -DriveLetter $letter -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "$label" -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -Force -Confirm:$false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to simplify things a tad ... [*grin*]

```
$DiskPrepInfo = @'
DiskNumber, DriveLetter, Label
1, D, SQL
2, E, Data
3, F, Logs
4, G, TempDB
5, K, Backups
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($DPI_Item in $DiskPrepInfo)
    {
    # you may want to add a "Start-Sleep -Seconds [long enuf to finish]" between each of these
    Set-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -IsOffline $False
    Set-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -IsReadOnly $False
    Initialize-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -PartitionStyle GPT
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -DriveLetter $DPI_Item.DriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
    $FV_Params = @{
        DriveLetter = $DPI_Item.DiskNumber
        FileSystem = 'NTFS'
        NewFileSystemLabel = $DPI_Item.Label
        # it's tempting to use "64KB" here [*grin*] 
        AllocationUnitSize = 65536
        Force = $True
        Confirm = $False
        }
    Format-Volume @FV_Params
    }
```

this is NOT tested! [*grin*] not only do i not have any disks to test on ... i don't have those cmdlets. they are not included with win7ps5.1.

Comment: Nicely done (the cmdlets require Windows 8+ / Windows Server 2012+); while I personally don't know, it's fair to assume that (a) these cmdlets operate _synchronously_ and (b) even if they don't, `Start-Sleep -Seconds [long enuf to finish]` sounds like an ill-advised way to ensure synchronous operation.

Comment: @mklement0 - yep, it's a prime example of something that needs testing. inserting delays ... not a nice thing. yes, it's simple ... but it is far too fiddly. a better way would be to test for "is it done", but i have no ideas on how to do that. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

```
$DiskPrepInfo = @'
DiskNumber, DriveLetter, Label
1, D, SQL
2, E, Data
3, F, Logs
4, G, TempDB
5, K, Backups
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($DPI_Item in $DiskPrepInfo)
    {
    # you may want to add a "Start-Sleep -Seconds [long enuf to finish]" between each of these
    Set-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -IsOffline $False
    Set-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -IsReadOnly $False
    Initialize-Disk -Number $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -PartitionStyle GPT
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -DriveLetter $DPI_Item.DriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter $DPI_Item.DiskNumber -FileSystem NTFS -AllocationUnitSize 65536 -NewFileSystemLabel $DPI_Item.Label -Confirm:$false
    }
```

Comment: This is hard to read; put the code in a code block to preserve formatting